# Calling Facebook graph api method using secondary thread in iphone

Tags: iphone

I want to call Facebook graph api method like this ,

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(threadCallToGetFriendsFromFacebook) toTarget:self  withObject:nil];

-(void)threadCallToGetFriendsFromFacebook
{
NSAutoreleasePool *FacebookPool=[[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];

@try 
{
    [_facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/friends" andDelegate:self];
    [FacebookPool release];
}
@catch (NSException * e) {
    [FacebookPool release];
}
```

}

But it didn't fire a Facebook delegate method

```
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result
```

I want to know , can we call a Facebook api method using secondary thread? is it possible ?
Plz help me?

Thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 0):

Facebook requests are asynchronous (they are on their own thread), so why do you want to do this manually ?